# Unable to resolve macro precedence in C?

Tags: c, visual-c++, c-preprocessor

I was trying to write a simple C program. Here I have defined a macro.

```
#define NAME(x) #x ## _bingo
```

Now which one (`#` and `##`) of them will be solved first?

I am stuck :) . I tried to google about such macro precedence. But couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: nothing, just trying to learn, you can consider it an experiment !!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Now which one (# and ##) of them will be solved first?

The standard says:

> **16.3.2 The # operator [cpp.stringize]**
>
> 2/ [...] The order of evaluation of `#` and `##` operators is unspecified.

But what are you trying to achieve here? It seems that:

```
#define NAME(x) x ## _bingo
```

Would be enough if you want to concatenate the `x` token and `_bingo`.

Example:

```
NAME(foo)
```

would be expanded as

```
foo_bingo
```

**EDIT :**

If you want to *stringify* the generated token with the `NAME` macro, here is an example on how you can do this (solve the problem of macro replacement -> *16.3.1 of the standard*):

```
#define NAME(x)  x##_bingo

// Converts the parameter x to a string after macro replacement
// on x has been performed if needed.
#define STRINGIFY(x)    DO_STRINGIFY(x)
#define DO_STRINGIFY(x) #x
 
int main() {
    std::string n  = STRINGIFY( NAME( foo ) );
    std::string n2 = DO_STRINGIFY( NAME(foo) );
    
    // Will print foo_bingo as expected
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
    
    // Will print NAME( foo ) because the macro NAME is not expanded
    std::cout << n2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
foo_bingo
NAME(foo)
```

Comment: i want to first concatenate and then stringify it ?

Comment: @AmitBhaira: With a second macro: `STRINGIFY(x ## _bingo)`

Comment: oh!! great thanks :) so at a time i can just solve one, right ?

Comment: @AmitBhaira The `STRINGIFY` example of @Mike Seymour si perfect but you have to take care because `STRINGIFY( NAME(foo) )` will not work as expected (*16.3.1 of the standard*). Because macro replacement will not be done. Take a look here: http://ideone.com/zDfe1Q

Comment: @PierreFourgeaud  Where i can find these standards as you just mentioned 16.3.2 , could you provide me a link where i can read all of them ?

Comment: Thank you 3 :) i really admire you for it sir . :)